# MySQL return string after date comparsion

Tags: mysql

Can MYSQL return a specific string with date comparsion?

I have a table with field id and field myDate only.

I would like to do something like

`select myDate, (myDate < today) as expired from myTable`

I expect the result like these.

05/05/2016, true

06/05/2016, false

07/05/2016, false

Comment: Absolutely you can, but mysql take `true`/`false` as 1/0

Comment: Thanks for bring this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
select myDate, IF(myDate < CURDATE(), 'true', 'false') as expired from myTable
```

Comment: Thanks. but the correct wording should be `select myDate, IF(myDate < CURDATE(), "true", "false") as expired from myTable`

Comment: Perhaps, but you didn't ask about the comparison per se so I assumed "today" to be a column in your table.